# Where are the client connection settings in mongodb stored?

Tags: mongodb

lets say i connect to a mongodb instance using this connection string `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?connectTimeoutMS=10000`

where (in which db and collection) does the server store this information that this is the connectTimeout etc? or are these not stored at all?

is there a way to find that it was properly set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect timeout is a client option. The server does not use it for anything and is unaware of what its value is for any of the clients.